# Long multiplication of two numbers given as strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, multiplication

I am trying to solve a problem of multiplication. I know that Python supports very large numbers and it can be done but what I want to do is

1. Enter 2 numbers as strings.
2. Multiply those two numbers in the same manner as we used to do in school.

Basic idea is to convert the code given in the link below to Python code but I am not very good at C++/Java. What I want to do is to understand the code given in the link below and apply it for Python.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/

I am stuck at the addition point.
I want to do it it like in the image given below

[image]

So I have made a list which stores the values of **i**<sup>th</sup> digit of first number to **j**<sup>th</sup> digit of second. Please help me to solve the addition part.

```
def mul(upper_no,lower_no):
    upper_len=len(upper_no)
    lower_len=len(lower_no)
    list_to_add=[]  #saves numbers in queue to add in the end

    for lower_digit in range(lower_len-1,-1,-1):
        q=''  #A queue to store step by step multiplication of numbers
        carry=0

        for upper_digit in range(upper_len-1,-1,-1):
            num2=int(lower_no[lower_digit])
            num1=int(upper_no[upper_digit])
            print(num2,num1)
            x=(num2*num1)+carry
            if upper_digit==0:
                q=str(x)+q
            else:
                if x>9:
                    q=str(x%10)+q
                    carry=x//10
                else:
                    q=str(x%10)+q
                    carry=0
                    num=x%10
        print(q)
        list_to_add.append(int(''.join(q)))
    print(list_to_add)

mul('234','567')
```

I have `[1638,1404,1170]` as a result for the function call `mul('234','567')` I am supposed to add these numbers but stuck because these numbers have to be shifted for each list. for example 1638 is supposed to be added as 16380 + 1404 with 6 aligning with 4, 3 with 0 and 8 with 4 and so on. Like:

```
    1638
   1404x
  1170xx
--------
  132678
--------
```

Comment: You might find this of value - RosettaCode [Python](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Python) tasks.

Comment: @GuyCoder YEah there is one link regarding the same problem but I could not understand it as all this Python thing is new to me.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, your question can be reduced to 1) how do I raise elements in a list to powers of 10 (1, 10, 100, ...), and 2) how do I get a sum of the resulting list. Is this correct?

Comment: @Georgy Something like this. But I want to multiply two very big numbers ( like very large) and multiply them like in the picture shown. I have ** [1638,1404,1170]**  as a result for the function call  **mul('234','567')** . I have nowhere to go now. I am supposed to add these numbers but stuck because these numbers have to be shifted for each list. for example **1638** is supposed to be added as **16380** + **1404**  with 6 aligning with 4, 3 with 0 and 8 with 4 and so on. How can I shift ?

Comment: The image is incorrect. You need to be careful about the horizontal placement. Normally, I would right-pad with an increasing number of zeros. But you can just add the row number to an index. Good luck.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yeah I have thought about it adding with 1 extra zero each time but then how are you supposed to add those number in the loop? It'll be creating an extra loop plus all the extra overhead if I have both strings as length in the range 2^99999

Comment: If you want it to "look like that" then just do that. Pad with spaces on the right. You are not supposed to be adding those numbers anyway, you should be adding the digits. And you should probably show the carry. Have you considered writing a separate function to perform the addition on the list of intermediaries?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. I've added a `place` variable to keep track of what power of 10 each intermediate value should be multiplied by, and used the [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function to produce the intermediate accumulated sums that doing so produces (and you want to show).

Note I have also reformatted your code so it closely follows [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in an effort to make it more readable.

```
from itertools import accumulate
import operator


def mul(upper_no, lower_no):
    upper_len = len(upper_no)
    lower_len = len(lower_no)
    list_to_add = []  # Saves numbers in queue to add in the end

    place = 0
    for lower_digit in range(lower_len-1, -1, -1):
        q = ''  # A queue to store step by step multiplication of numbers
        carry = 0

        for upper_digit in range(upper_len-1, -1, -1):
            num2 = int(lower_no[lower_digit])
            num1 = int(upper_no[upper_digit])
            print(num2, num1)
            x = (num2*num1) + carry
            if upper_digit == 0:
                q = str(x) + q
            else:
                if x>9:
                    q = str(x%10) + q
                    carry = x//10
                else:
                    q = str(x%10) + q
                    carry = 0
                    num = x%10
        print(q)
        list_to_add.append(int(''.join(q)) * (10**place))
        place += 1

    print(list_to_add)
    print(list(accumulate(list_to_add, operator.add)))


mul('234', '567')
```

Output:

```
7 4
7 3
7 2
1638
6 4
6 3
6 2
1404
5 4
5 3
5 2
1170
[1638, 14040, 117000]
[1638, 15678, 132678]
```

Comment: That is the whole point. I have added '0' for each iteration, starting from 2nd and converted it to int and then sum(list). But I am working on a hypothetical scenario what if " **the number is too big that Python is not able to understand it** " . That is why I am using this approach.that works by converting each string character as integer and multiplying it like we do on paper in school.

Comment: There is no hypothetical number Python can't handle -- although your computer or OS may run out of memory trying to let it. Guess I don't get it your "whole point".

Comment: I know for a fact that there is no such case that's why I used "hypothetical". Ok! so let me put it other way **I am working on a problem which mimics/implements the multiplication of two, 2+ digits  numbers, done by children in school using Python**

Comment: @Mahesh So, what is the exact problem about the solution that Martin provided?

Comment: @Mahesh If it's about the result printed as a list, just replace `print(list(accumulate(list_to_add, operator.add)))` with `print(sum(list_to_add))`

Comment: @Mahesh: IMO (obviously), I think the `list(accumulate(list_to_add, operator.add))` part answers your question about how "to solve the addition part" and that using the added `place` variable puts the right number into the `list_to_add`. Since that's apparently not it, I'm going to vote to close your answer as being unclear.